# Can a UDP multicast server send packets outside LAN?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, udp, multicast

I'm in the process of making a multiplayer game, where the players' movements are sent over the network and their positions are stored in the server. I've been told that UDP would be best since it doesn't rely on constant connection and it won't matter if the client misses a packet. The clients could be on any router, not necessarily within the server's LAN.

Is it possible to set up a server that the clients can connect to that will send all of them periodic updates of the positions of nearby objects/players?

I don't want to have to send packets to each individual client, and I heard multicasting can solve this problem, but every example I've seen only sends packets over a local network. Can I multicast past routers, and if so, how can I do that in Java? (And explain it to me like I have no idea what I'm doing, which is mostly true)

Ex.

Server has IP address 71.10.200.133

Client A has IP address 38.49.339.293

Client B has IP address 37.28.487.388

...

Client Z has IP address 43.38.382.949

Client A sends an update about the player's position to Server

Server sends update to B-Z without iterating a packet to each individual client. How do I accomplish this (if it's possible)?

Comment: A multicast address is 32 bits in IPv4. There's no way to be able to convey that much granularity; a single IP address in your set will have 32 bits of data/entropy defining it.

Comment: @hexafraction 'That much granularity' as what? What are you talking about?

Comment: @EJP The OP's wish to send packets to 26 given IP addresses of game clients.

Comment: @hexafraction You can do that with one multicast address. That's what multicast *means.*

Comment: Multicast is just UDP sent to a multicast address. In order for it to move to other subnets, the router has to pass them to the next interface. The multicast subscriber protocol to define a hierarchical topology on which the packets are conveyed exits, but *may* not be allowed/implemented on public internet routers. It is *required* on ipv6. In theory multicast allows a single packet to be sent to millions of endpoints using only routers to distribute them.

Comment: @wilsotc Multicasting was rarely allowed across WAN,i.e. ISP/host usually did't support it because 1) it's resource intensive for routers 2) creates bandwidth billing/monitoring difficulties for the host/ISP as a small amount of bandwidth originating from the sender can multiplex into a huge amount of bandwidth after a few hops. Researching WAN networks built/upgrade to support ipv6, only some of them support multicast addresses. "required on ipv6" surprises me(was that separate statement from "may not be [prior to ipv6]"?). I may have misunderstood though, but I think it's still optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multicasts will traverse a router if and only if the router allows it. Unless you're in control of all the routers between you and your clients, the answer to your question is 'no'.

Comment: So I should just send individual packets to each client?

Comment: You don't have any choice.

Answer (score 0):

Multicast packets are broadcasts, thus they reach each node on that subnet. For you to send a multicast packet out on the web is not an effecient nor smart way of sending data.

For LAN based traffic:

> Multicast is fine

But, for internet traffic I would suggest making a:

> UDPClient

or

> TCPClient

for internet based traffic and possibly multicast for LAN based (to mix things up a bit).

**For internet traffic:** Keep in mind, clients will need to initiate the connection first since most routers (household) have a firewall blocking all NEW outside-to-in traffic. So create a socket to listen over a designated port/ports for any incoming connections and from there on use which ever method of packet broadcasting/sending you like

Answer (score 0):

You do also have the option of using Multicast proxies or Layer 2 VPNs if you have the capabilities. L2TP, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_2_Tunneling_Protocol
A layer 2 VPN would relay unicast and multicast packets.
That would basically allow you to control the routers as EJP suggested above.
This questions also 3 year old so you've probably already figured a way to do it by now.